# Getting distribution group details with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to recreate hundreds of distribution groups in a new (O365) environment.  I’ve no access to the source system other than to work with their techs to provide them scripts that they’ll run for me.

I wrote a script to spit out the names of all the lists that my users are members of (security and distribution).  I’d like to write another to cycle through each distribution group and provide me with details of that group.  I don’t see how to do that.

I see that Set-DistributionGroup will happily let me set the AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers (and a million other fields) but I don’t see that Get_DistributionGroup will output those values for me.  How do I do this to ensure I’m not recreating an open group for HR that should have been MemberJoinRestriction enabled (for example)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please copy and paste the script you are having difficulty with into the question as text. Use the `{}` icon to make it look like code. Tell what it does and tell what you want it to do.

Comment: PowerShell will limit the resulting properties. If you do `Get-DistributionGroup -Resultsize Unlimited | Format-List *` you should see the rest of these properties too.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I'm not a PowerShell guy (obvs.), but here's what I wrote that works.  I'm sure I'm not taking advantage of PowerShell at all here, so wanna suggest how I could improve? Like why did I have to use $temp? Quicker to check the array first before I Get-ADGroup again? etc.

```
# Start with a user list, get the groups eash is a part of, get information about the group
# if it is mail-enabled then add it to an array, remove duplicates, then store all the
# information about that DistributionGroup into a .csv

$groups = @() 

ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content c:\Users\sid.sowder\Desktop\CEGusers.txt)) {

    $MyGroups = Get-ADuser $user -Properties * | select memberof -ExpandProperty memberof

    ForEach ($MyGroup in $MyGroups) {
        $temp = Get-ADGroup $MyGroup -Properties *

        if ($temp.mail -ne $null) {
            $groups += $temp.SamAccountName
        }

    }    
}

$groups = $groups | sort -unique

Foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $group |
        Select * |
        Export-CSV C:\Users\Sid.Sowder\Desktop\distlistdetail.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```